# Can a constructor definition be prefixed with the "class" keyword?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, compiler-bug

Please tell me why my program gets compiled and executed when I treat the constructor as a class without private and public sections by just writing the word `class` before it as follows:

```
class sample
{
private:
    int a,b;

public:
    class sample(int a1){a = a1;}
};
```

Comment: This is not valid code.

Comment: What do you mean by "executed" anyway? What happens?

Comment: Your code failed to compile by g++, and it does not seem to be correct c++ code. If you want to know why particular compiler accepts it at least publish your compiler name and version.

Comment: The code does compile under VS2012.

Comment: I think OP understands the code is not correct and is wondering why it compiles anyway (for some compilers, at least). I'm wondering the same thing.

Comment: *If* it compiled even though the obvious syntax error, what compiler are you using? And what version of it?

Comment: @dlf can you try to compile with disabled MS extensions?

Comment: @Slava It still accepts it. That's also true with the highest warning level enabled.

Comment: @dlf thanks. How VS treats this code as constructor declaration or inner class?

Comment: @Slava It interprets it as a constructor (you get "no appropriate default constructor" if you try to instantiate a `sample` without an `int` parameter).

Comment: Also reproducible in VS2013.

Comment: @dlf thanks! I would imagine they just used the same gramma rule for constructor as for class instance declaration ie: `[struct|class] name instance;` but that just a speculation.

Comment: @user3874009 Consider adding the compiler-bug tag to your question (and editing the title?) since that's what it appears to be.

Answer (score 5):

That isn't valid, and my compiler rejects it. Constructors must be declared using the class name, with no class key (i.e. no `class`, `struct` or `union` keyword).

Perhaps your compiler accepts elaborated type specifiers as constructor names; but if so, that's a non-standard extension, and you shouldn't rely on it. If you're lucky, the compiler might provide an option to disable extensions, which you should use if you don't want to be tied to that compiler for ever.

Comment: @chris: Good point. I couldn't remember offhand whether a union could have a constructor, but it turns out that it can.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, only since C++11.

Answer (score 1):

The code you've provided violates the spec and technically shouldn't compile:

> 12.1 Constructors
>
> <sup>1</sup> Constructors do not have names. A special declarator syntax is used to declare or define the constructor. The syntax uses:
>
> — an optional decl-specifier-seq in which each decl-specifier is either a function-specifier or constexpr,
>
> — the constructor’s class name, and
>
> — a parameter list
>
> in that order. In such a declaration, optional parentheses around the constructor class name are ignored.

(*function-specifier* means one of `inline`, `virtual`, or `explicit`--see 7.1.2/1--but virtual constructors are disallowed by 12.1/4)

That said, Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 and 2013 (at a minimum) accept it. This appears to be a bug in those compilers.

Update: Microsoft is aware of this issue, but has (understandably) decided not to bother fixing it.

[Bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/794504/keyword-struct-before-constructor-name)